# JavaScript length property (basic)

Tags: javascript

I apply ".length" on the element has id="name", but it counts 29 instead of 14. I wonder where is my mistake? It would be nice if someone can let me know. Thank you!

```js
var name=document.getElementById('name');
var totalTiles=document.getElementById('totalTiles');

totalTiles.textContent=name.length;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="heading"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Custom sign:</th>
            <td id='name'>Montague House
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Total tiles:</th>
            <td id='totalTiles'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>Pay Now</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `console.log` the `name` element itself instead of it's length and you will see why

Comment: `name.textContent.length`

Comment: Spaces count...

Comment: Where is the is event ,click input or more ?

Comment: You want the textContent.length of ’name’.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoint and validating what is document.getElementById(“name”) is returning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the name variable is the entire dom element (*td*).

Try using **innerText** to get the required value

```js
var name = document.getElementById('name').innerText;
var totalTiles = document.getElementById('totalTiles');

totalTiles.textContent = name.length;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="heading"></div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Custom sign:</th>
      <td id='name'>Montague House
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total tiles:</th>
      <td id='totalTiles'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button>Pay Now</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the name variable returns [object HTMLTableCellElement] and not the string you intended to return. The length of the [object HTMLTableCellElement] is 29 so that's what the length property returns.

To get the value of the actual string you need to count the length of the variable after applying the .innerText property.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are returning the entire `HTMLTableCellElement` on the `getElementById` selector.

I would recommend you to use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to get the text values. However, you should be using `textContent` instead, as it utilises the text vaules and does not need to parse HTML, thus it is faster.

In addition, you might want to use the `trim()` method to remove the trailing white spaces.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name').textContent.trim();
const totalTiles = document.getElementById('totalTiles');

totalTiles.textContent = name.length;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="heading"></div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Custom sign:</th>
      <td id='name'>Montague House
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total tiles:</th>
      <td id='totalTiles'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button>Pay Now</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help!